# Trying to execute behavior by default but AutonomousLife with blue eyes cancel it

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I have a serious problem with the NAO.

I am trying to run a NAO project in choregraphe so that it starts by default. When I run it, it appears to be working, but it doesn't pick up the speech recognition of my project.

In order to run the project, you have to face it, have the autonomousLife pick you up, get blue eyes, causing the behaviour to stop, and then get out of the face recognition area, and then it runs the behaviour again and this time it goes. It's as if the first execution didn't work and you have to stop it by entering another behaviour, which is the one with the blue eyes that recognises your face and voice.

And another problem we have is that if we go into the application, if we go in front of it and it recognises our face and voice, it takes us out of our application, putting the blue eyes again.

It has been tested with the basic channel, without the basic channel, with the autonomouslife deactivated and activated (we need it to be activated because the robot in the application does a dance). We have also put the following in the manifest:

We have tried with this launch trigger condition, without it, we have used the solitary, interactive and no natural and it still does not work. We can't get it to run at startup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your behavior should be of nature "Interactive" instead of "Solitary". Otherwise, any other "Interactive" behavior may take over yours.